# react-addons-transition-group's `componentWillLeave` equivalent for React Native??

Tags: animation, reactjs, react-native, react-animated

The `componentWillLeave` feature and the corresponding callback is a powerful feature I haven't seen in RN. Without it, you're always forced into producing very crappy code using additional states to make sure an element stays on the page/phone until its animation is complete, when ideally some boolean state from redux simply triggers the removal of the element while respecting its `willleave` animation.

So does anyone have any ideas how to accomplish this consistently in RN without having to write custom code every time to make sure the element stays rendered until you animate it away??

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I just landed here from a google search on the topic so I'll give my 2 cents on it.

This library should represent a 1:1 replacement for `react-addons-transition-group` for RN and comes with support for `componentWillLeave` method you can implement. It supports both `componentWillEnter` and `componentWillLeave`.

Link to the library: [react-native-transitiongroup](https://github.com/madsleejensen/react-native-transitiongroup)